# How can I get a CanoScan 8400F flatbed scanner working in Ubuntu?

Tags: scanner, canon, sane

I'd like to use a CanoScan 8400F scanner with my laptop, which is running Xubuntu 18.04.  I can detect the scanner with both `lsusb`, which returns

> Bus 002 Device 006: ID 04a9:221e Canon, Inc. CanoScan 8400F

and `sudo sane-find-scanner`, which returns

> found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Canon], product=0x221e [CanoScan], chip=GL842) at libusb:002:006

However, neither `scanimage` nor SimpleScan will detect the scanner.  I note that running `sane-find-scanner` without permissions also does *not* detect the scanner.  A visit to the [Sane supported devices page](http://www.sane-project.org/lists/sane-mfgs-cvs.html#Z-CANON) suggests that my scanner should be supported, though that's apparently as of Sane 1.0.31.  I appear to be running Sane 1.0.27.  I've run `sudo apt-get update` to no effect.

What am I missing?  Is there any way to get this to work short of compiling the latest version of Sane myself?  (Because I'm not going to do that.  It's not worth the trouble.)

Thanks,

--John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Ubuntu 21.04

Have you renamed `~/.sane` to `~/.sane-bkup` to clear away old settings?

For my own install, I had previously installed older versions of "backends" and had to remove them.  `ippusbxd` is not installed, it has been replaced by `ipp-usb` whose current version is installed.

Have you cleaned up old attempts at getting this working?  They will impact your results.

Have you ensured that in the `/etc/sane.d/genesys.conf` file has the line for the 8400F `usb 0x04a9 0x221e` uncommented.

My tests:

1. `simple-scan` automatically detects my Canon CanoScan 8400F.
2. `xsane 0.999` automatically detects 8400F.
3. `gscan2pdf` automatically detects 8400F.
4. Disappointingly `scangearmp2` does not detect scanner.  I liked the "auto-crop" features when scanning multiple photos.  Shame it cannot use the code present in tested options 1-3.  Contained in `/lib/bjlib` are two files `canon_mp2.conf` and `cifmx530.conf` which may limit detected scanners.
5. `skanlite` installed from a `snap` also disappointingly did not detect scanner.  This is because the `/snap/skanlite/current/etc/sane.d/genesys.conf` is out-of-date.
6. `skanlite` installed from `apt-get install` automatically detects 8400F.

When the 8400F is powered up and turned ON
`find-sane-scanner` generates:
`found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Canon], product=0x221e [CanoScan], chip=GL842) at libusb:002:009` similar to yours.

`scanimage -L` returns `genesys:libusb:002:009`  which shows it does detect scanner
`scanimage --device-name 'genesys:libusb:002:009' --format=jpeg > me.jpeg` generates a gray scaled image.  I haven't played with option settings as I prefer `simple-scan`, `gscan2pdf`, and `xsane`

I also have a Canon MX530 series network multi-function scanner, printer, fax and that is detected by options 1-3.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response.  I will certainly keep it in mind if I have further scanner problems in the future.  Luckily for me, at some point not too long after I posted my question Sane auto-updated and the scanner has worked with my laptop ever since.

Answer (score 1):

If

```
    scanimage -L
```

does not provide a list of scanners it finds, then

maybe

```
    sudo scanimage -L
```

will work. Because scanimage offers a lot of parameters on the command line, you may be able to try different combinations.

The Canon website doesn't offer any Linux drivers, though the Windows driver section looks pretty rich.  Would you consider installing a dual boot on your machine for Windows or set up a VM under Ubuntu to try them?

Comment: I shouldn't need to dual boot.  If I can't get the scanner working with my laptop, I've got an older Windows machine that ought to work.  I'd simply prefer to use my laptop.  But I thank you for the suggestion.